# Failed to Configure TFS Team Project Collection

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, microsoft-test-manager

Facing this issue while configuring test controller.

The user for the test controller is a member of the TeamTestControllerAdmins group and test controller is configured for the correct team project collection.

Please look into the logs and tell if i have to make any changes?

[Logs2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCGXJ.png)

[Logs1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MS7jL.png)

[Logs3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGESq.png)

Comment: Could you provide few more details like the TFS version and the log is missing the error portion.. could you provide the full log including the portion it is giving the error.. or is this the full log you have?

Comment: @ChamindaC thanks for the reply.
I've added full logs now. please check
TFS version - Version 14.102.25423.0

Comment: Test Controller version - 15.0.27617.1

Comment: According to the log info, the error occurs when checking the controller service account have enough permission, then the service stopped. Have you double check the account permission setting? And also suggest you to go through the official tutorial which maybe helpful [Setting Up Test Controllers in Lab Environments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh546460.aspx)